# Where am I going wrong with my math here to try and extract the correct hours from a date time?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a countdown timer and for some reason I can not get the hours to display correctly. No matter what, the hours is always shown as zero. Can someone double check my math to see where I am going wrong?

```
let countTitle = '';
let countDate = '';
let countDateValue = new Date();
const second = 1000;
const minute = second * 60;
const hour = minute * 60;
const day = hour * 24;
const today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];


function countdown() {
    const todayValue = new Date().getTime();
    
    const difference = countDateValue - todayValue;
    
    const days = Math.floor(difference / day);
    const hours = Math.floor((difference % day) / hour);
    const minutes = Math.floor((difference % hour) / minute);
    const seconds = Math.floor((difference % minute) / second);
    
}

function getData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    countTitle = e.srcElement[0].value;
    countValue = e.srcElement[1].value;
    
    countDateValue = new Date(countValue).getTime();
    
    countdown();
}
```

Comment: it's unclear and incomplete, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  what is e.srcElement ?

Comment: You need to show how and when you are calling *countDown*. In `countDateValue - todayValue`, both variables are initialised with `new Date()`, so if the difference in time between the global code that initialises *countDateValue* and the function call that initialises *todayValue* is less than 1 hour, then the hour value will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code, it gives me perfect results unless input dates itself is wrong.

When I ran your code thorough some sample dates(1619628379441, 1619227379441), it results me perfectly `4 15 23 20`.

```js
let countTitle = '';
let countDate = '';
let countDateValue = new Date();
const second = 1000;
const minute = second * 60;
const hour = minute * 60;
const day = hour * 24;
const today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];


function countdown() {
  const todayValue = 1619227379441; //new Date().getTime();

  const difference = countDateValue - todayValue;

  const days = Math.floor(difference / day);
  const hours = Math.floor((difference % day) / hour);
  const minutes = Math.floor((difference % hour) / minute);
  const seconds = Math.floor((difference % minute) / second);
  
  console.log(days, hours, minutes, seconds)

}

function getData(e) {
  countDateValue =  1619628379441; // new Date(countValue).getTime();
  countdown();
}

getData();
```